# How to call setProcessMitigationPolicy using JNA

Tags: java, c++, native, jna

I'm trying to convert this piece of C++ code into Java code via JNA:

```cpp
PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY signaturePolicy = {};
signaturePolicy.MicrosoftSignedOnly = true;
SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessSignaturePolicy, &signaturePolicy, sizeof(signaturePolicy));
```

I already have the function `SetProcessMitigationPolicy` from `Kernel32.dll` and I'm able to call it, but how to pass such parameters?

Can you please provide an example of it?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the following code, but it is still not working. Is the function declaration correct? Apparently, the function returns true and I'm not getting any error.

```java
// Main

private static final Kernel32 kernel32 = Kernel32.INSTANCE;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY signaturePolicy = new PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY();
    signaturePolicy.MicrosoftSignedOnly = 1;

    signaturePolicy.write();

    BaseTSD.SIZE_T dwLength = new BaseTSD.SIZE_T(signaturePolicy.size());

    boolean success = kernel32.SetProcessMitigationPolicy(8, signaturePolicy.getPointer(), dwLength);

    System.out.println("Result: " + success);

    while (true);
}
// PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY

@Structure.FieldOrder({"MicrosoftSignedOnly"})
public final class PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY extends Structure {

    public int MicrosoftSignedOnly;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SetProcessMitigationPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setprocessmitigationpolicy) function has three arguments.

```
BOOL SetProcessMitigationPolicy(
  PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY MitigationPolicy,
  PVOID                     lpBuffer,
  SIZE_T                    dwLength
);
```

The first argument is a [PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-process_mitigation_policy) enumeration.  This is a simple integer (starting at 0) indicating which policy to use.  Your sample code shows the `ProcessSignaturePolicy` member of the enumeration.  This is just the integer 8.

```java
int MitigationPolicy = 8;
```

Your example code shows you're using the `PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY` structure as the second argument.  This is actually mapped as a 32-bit union with either a `DWORD` (can be mapped as an int) and a structure with bit fields totalling 32 bits.  JNA does not have a means to map bit fields so you need to directly set those bits.  So I'd simplify the mapping and just map this structure as only the `Flags` field:

```
@FieldOrder ({"Flags"})
class PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY extends Structure {
  public int Flags;
}
```

MS Docs specify bit fields [start at the least significant bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-bit-fields?view=msvc-160). So the equivalent of `signaturePolicy.MicrosoftSignedOnly = true;` is to set the least significant bit to 1.

```java
PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY signaturePolicy 
    = new PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY();
signaturePolicy.Flags = 1;
// alternately, since Flags is initialized to 0, the direct
// counterpart to setting MicrosoftSignedOnly = true is:
// signaturePolicy.Flags |= 0x1;
```

The second function parameter is a pointer (`PVOID`) which your example shows is the address of the structure.  So you should pass `signaturePolicy.getPointer()` for that parameter.

Normally when passing a `Structure` to a function it autowrites the Java value to the native memory.  We'll only be passing the pointer to the structure so we need to manually `write()` the value to the native memory before passing it.

```java
signaturePolicy.write();
// now pass signaturePolicy.getPointer()
```

The third parameter is a `SIZE_T` size of the structure.

```
SIZE_T dwLength = new SIZE_T(signaturePolicy.size());
```

---

Updating the answer to address the update in the question.

The mapping is correct per the answer; your variable name choice for the structure mapping could be misleading since you're using the name of a bit field for the entire 32-bit `Flags` value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer its pretty clear, but apparently my code still not working. Is the function declaration correct?     `boolean SetProcessMitigationPolicy(int policy, Pointer lpBuffer, SIZE_T dwLength);`

Comment: Apparently, the function returns `true` and im not getting any error.. Yes, i added `write()`

Comment: Unfortunatly stack doesnt allow me to send the currect code (message too long), so ive uploaded it to pastebin. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/izH3k4C1

Comment: The code in the pastebin looks good (other than the naming of the `int` field could be misleading.).  The docs say "If the function succeeds, it returns TRUE." so how do you know it is not working?

Comment: Well, basically because `ProcessSignaturePolicy` should: `The policy of a process that can restrict image loading to those images that are either signed by Microsoft, by the Windows Store, or by Microsoft, the Windows Store and the Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).`  the problem is that i can still load dlls into the process, and that happens only if im doing it with jna. If i do the same thing in c++ (on a separate program), when trying to inject/load a dll it shows me a MessageBox and wont load it. Here i can load the dll without any problem, even if it returns true.

Comment: Gotcha.  I guess that's probably a different question and would need more info on the surrounding code and how you're injecting the other DLLs.

Comment: @DanielWiddis "*alternately, to self-document the bit flip*" - just FYI, `Flags = 1;` and `Flags |= 0x1` are not the same thing. `Flags = 1;` will set the least significant bit to 1 and all other bits to 0. `Flags |= 0x1` will set the least significant bit to 1 and preserve the existing values of all other bits. And since `Flags` is uninitialized when `|=` is used in your example, you would potentially end up sending undefined flags to the function.

Comment: @DanielWiddis i mean, yes and not.. i know its a different field, but are the exact same functions.. so why should i work if i do it in c++ but not in java via jna?

Comment: @Remy-Lebeau Flags is a primitive int instance variable in a class which should initialize it to 0, no?

Comment: @donald-c-spencer the question is how you are loading the DLL in each different way.  JNA can load a dll independently of using a windows API function to los the DLL.

Comment: @DanielWiddis "*Flags is a primitive int instance variable in a class which should initialize it to 0, no?*" - my Java is a bit rusty, so I don't know whether that is true or not. I come from a C++ background, where that is certainly not true.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Not really, again. Im loading the dll in the exactly same way, with the exactly same tool so.. I dont really think is related to how i load the dll.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Gotcha. Yeah, it's part of the Java spec, and coming from a JNA perspective equivalent to initializing that structure with all 0 bits (the Java default, and if Java didn't do it, JNA initializes non-primitive structure members using defaults constructors).  The `|=` would be directly equivalent to setting that one bit structure memory true. I've clarified the comment.

Comment: @DonaldC.Spencer I suggest a new question showing how you're loading the DLL since this question appears to at least be executing the function as expected and there's some other winapi behavior that needs new sets of eyes on it.